# Get the rest in successively divisions

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm new in Assembler and in this forum. I tried to get the rest in successively divisions, to finally print the results. Simulating a decimal to binary conversor.

I tried to make a for, in this for, I did the div operation and then an if from which I took each remainder by separating 0 and 1 with the IS_ZERO and IS_ONE tags, but isn't printing anything. I'm lost and don't know what I failed.

Thanks for the help.

```
mov cx, 26d

jmp short @1@86
@1@58:
mov ax,cx   
mov bl, 2  
div bl     
mov cl,al 
mov dh,ah 
cmp ah,1   
JZ IS_ZERO
jmp IS_ONE

IS_ZERO:
mov dl, 0; dl = dl + ASCII_0; Si dl = 0 -> dl = ASCII_0 ; Si dl = 1 -> dl = ASCII_0 + 1 = ASCII_1
      mov ah, 2
      int 21h
      jmp short @1@86
IS_ONE:
mov dl, 1; dl = dl + ASCII_0; Si dl = 0 -> dl = ASCII_0 ; Si dl = 1 -> dl = ASCII_0 + 1 = ASCII_1
      mov ah, 2
      int 21h
      jmp short @1@86
      

@1@86:
cmp al,1 
jg short @1@58
```

Comment: You're printing the binary bytes 0 and 1, which aren't printable, instead of the ASCII characters.  You have a comment saying to add ASCII '0' but you don't ever actually do it. Try `mov dl, '0'` and `mov dl, '1'`.

Comment: By the way, `div` is a very inefficient way to divide by 2; think about how to rewrite using `shr`.

Comment: And I'm confused how your initial `jmp @1@86` is going to work, since `al` is uninitialized at this point.  Unless you've left out the code where it gets initialized?

Comment: Oh, and your test is backwards: after `cmp` (which is really subtraction), the zero flag is set if the values were equal.  So you will jump to `IS_ZERO` if the remainder of the division was 1, and all your bits will be opposite.  Usually it's clearer to use the `je` and `jne` mnemonics after a `cmp`, which help you remember more easily what's going on.

Comment: Note that the value in CX is actually in binary when this code runs; the *assembler* converts from decimal in the ASCII source to a binary number in the machine code.  So your program is just converting a binary integer into a string of ASCII digits, using base 2.  Since those bases are the same, as Nate says you can do this *much* more efficiently with `shr cx` / `adc dl, '0'` to get a `'0'` or `'1'` character code, if DL was initially zero.